# Good libraries/technologies for video manipulation

Tags: video-processing, video-encoding

I'm looking into starting a project that will be heavily dependent on video manipulation, and I'd like to get some leads on good technologies that I can use.  My language of choice is typically Python, but it looks like the available libraries are either abandoned or insufficiently featureful.

Given that, I'm relatively agnostic on the specific language, though I'd prefer an option other than C or C++.  The requirements for the project include:

- Ability to handle a variety of common formats
- Video playback (variable speed playback a plus)
- Clipping sections out of larger videos
- Merging clips together into a single video
- Extracting single frames
- Multi-platform (preferably deployable on Windows/Mac/Linux)
- Free, or licenced at a reasonable cost for indie (but commercial) development

I haven't done much work with video on the desktop before, so I'm not sure if such a thing exists.  Are there any good candidates, or am I searching for a mythical beast here?

Comment: [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) works well for encoding. In fact, I believe it could everything you're asking for...

Comment: [MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) is what I was thinking of as far as encoding, but it plays well with FFMPEG.

Comment: There's also DIVx and Xvid, one commercial/proprietary, and the other free/open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some looking, I think [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) will probably do the trick (which under the hood, is a wrapper around FFMPEG).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried OpenCV ?
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/